# How to link one table field to different tables (inheritance mapping with doctrine)

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, multiple-inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I have a log table which has a special field named "source" that I would like to link to different tables depending on the source.

With native sql, I would do something like create 2 fields: source_id and source_type then customize the query to join to the appropriate tables. I wonder if there is any way to do this with doctrine?

---

Edit:

It seems like I can use inheritance mapping for this purpose. I run into another issue, however: lets say that I now have 2 fields: source and destination which maps to different objects. So an object can be either a source or a destination, I'm not sure what to do in this case.

In Doctrine example, it looks like I can create a parent class named Sourceable then have my objects entities inherit it, but now since these entities can be either Sourceable or Destinationable and PHP does not allow multiple inheritance I dont't know what to do.

---

Edit2:

I found a Ruby case that covers this issue:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/adjustment.rb

```
class Adjustment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :adjustable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :source, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :originator, polymorphic: true
```

> The source is where an adjustment was triggered from. For tax and
>   promotional adjustments, this will be the order itself. For shipping
>   adjustments, this will be the shipment which corresponds with the
>   shipping method for this order.
>
> The adjustable is the object being adjusted, which is the order.
>
> The originator is the object responsible for the adjustment. For
>   promotional adjustments, this will be a
>   Spree::Promotion::Actions::CreateAdjustment object. For tax
>   adjustments, a Spree::TaxRate object. For shipping adjustments, a
>   Spree::ShippingMethod object.

In their case the order can be either a source or an adjustable. Obviously this example is in ruby and with active record, but I wonder how I can do the same thing with Doctrine?